# Where should I ask questions about anger management?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where should I ask questions about anger management?

That's pretty much it, it's not the first time I break something because of sheer anger induced by other people and I need help controlling myself.

Is there anywhere I could ask?

Comment: I'd suggest your local GP, first off - and perhaps a referral to a psychiatrist / anger management specialist.

This really isn't something you should leave to strangers on the Internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [similar question](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/how-do-i-control-irritation-or-anger) on [Personal Productivity SE](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/) which might help you. Other than that, this is a topic that is best left to professionals, not Q&A sites.